# Classes folder instead of jars in Jetty configuration

Tags: java, ant, jetty

i'm migrating our web application from Tomcat 7 to Jetty 9. Ant task is used for Jetty startup. Jar files are located under WEB-INF/lib, class files are located under .build/classes.

The question is: is there any way to specify a folder containing class files instead of jars when performing annotations scan?

Below is Ant target configuration being used:

```
  <target name="jetty.run">
    <jetty.run tempDirectory="jetty-temp">
      <webApp war="app" contextpath="/">
        <attributes>
          <attribute name="org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern" value=".*/.*jsp-api-[^/]*\.jar$|.*/.*jsp-[^/]*\.jar$|.*/.*taglibs[^/]*\.jar$"/>
          <attribute name="org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.WebInfIncludeJarPattern" value=".*classes.*"/>
        </attributes>
        <classes dir=".build/classes">
          <include name="**/*.class" />
        </classes>
        <!--<lib dir=".build/classes">
          <include name="**/*.class" />
        </lib>-->
      </webApp>
      <connectors>
        <connector port="8090"/>
        <connector port="80"/>
      </connectors>
    </jetty.run>
  </target>
```

I've tried specifying classes element, but it seems to be ignored (.build folder resides at the same location where build.xml is). So the application code jar has to be built and copied to WEB-INF/lib in order for the application to start properly.

Jars reside in a standard location, but classes don't. Could this somehow cause this?

I'd be grateful for any help.

Thanks,
Vitaliy.

Comment: This is likely because jetty excludes directories that start with `"."` from the annotation scanning, as they are deemed to be hidden directories.

Comment: Oh, i see. Thanks! I will rename it to build (it's just that we used this folder for Eclipse-compiled classes, but it won't be a problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should open a bug on jetty for this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Jetty

The jetty-ant integration will add the  onto the classpath, but unfortunately it won't scan them for annotations.

If you upgraded to jetty-9.1.0.M0, then you could try specifying  the classes dir instead as , as we implemented annotation scanning on the extraClasspath with this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=416597. Note however,as Joakim says, that the dir name cannot start with a "." as this denotes a hidden directory.

regards
Jan

Comment: Thank you for help. I think that i'll stick with jar compilation for now, and will rename .build to build. And will wait for Jetty 9.1 final  version. Thanks again, Vitaliy.